# Set 'method' property with ri_cal gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, icalendar

We need to set the 'method' property as specified https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2445#section-4.7.2

> METHOD:REQUEST

How can this be done with ri_cal? This property seems to be missing.